# File downloader for update system is crashing

Tags: java, io, download, ioexception

I currently writing a app in java that installs mods into minecraft and the updater/first time run system is crashing when it trys to download the needed files, I'm getting the following exception

```
java.io.IOException: Access is denied
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.createNewFile(Unknown Source)
    at com.hachisoftware.mat.launcher.Util.getFileFromWeb(Util.java:43)
    at com.hachisoftware.mat.launcher.Main.setup(Main.java:22)
    at com.hachisoftware.mat.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:15)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: \Gui.jar (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.hachisoftware.mat.launcher.Util.getFileFromWeb(Util.java:71)
    at com.hachisoftware.mat.launcher.Util.getFileFromWeb(Util.java:45)
    at com.hachisoftware.mat.launcher.Main.setup(Main.java:22)
    at com.hachisoftware.mat.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:15)
java.io.IOException: Access is denied
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.createNewFile(Unknown Source)
    at com.hachisoftware.mat.launcher.Util.getFileFromWeb(Util.java:43)
    at com.hachisoftware.mat.launcher.Main.setup(Main.java:23)
    at com.hachisoftware.mat.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:15)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: \IntelliMod.jar (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.hachisoftware.mat.launcher.Util.getFileFromWeb(Util.java:71)
    at com.hachisoftware.mat.launcher.Util.getFileFromWeb(Util.java:45)
    at com.hachisoftware.mat.launcher.Main.setup(Main.java:23)
    at com.hachisoftware.mat.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:15)
```

I'm using the following code for the downloading

```
public static boolean getFileFromWeb(String location, String destination)
{
    String[] s = location.split("/");
    String s2 = s[s.length - 1];

    if(!"".equals(destination) && !(new File(destination)).exists())
        (new File(destination)).mkdir();

    File outFile = new File(destination, s2);
    if(!outFile.exists())
        try { outFile.createNewFile(); } catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

    return getFileFromWeb(outFile, location);
}

public static boolean getFileFromWeb(File outFile, String location)
{
    BufferedInputStream in = null;
    BufferedOutputStream out = null;

    try
    {
        URL url = new URL(location);
        URLConnection urlc = url.openConnection();
        urlc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "HS File Downloader(" + clientName + ")");
        in = new BufferedInputStream(urlc.getInputStream());
        out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outFile));
        byte[] dataBuffer = new byte[4096 * 1024];

        for(int line = in.read(dataBuffer); line != -1; line = in.read(dataBuffer))
        {
            out.write(dataBuffer, 0, line);
            out.flush();
        }

        in.close();
        out.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Any help or advice is welcome

Answer (score 0):

Exception clearly says

```
java.io.IOException: Access is denied

java.io.FileNotFoundException: \Gui.jar (Access is denied)
```

Make sure your program has rights to access file system.

Comment: I know that but it was working just before
It works if I do:
`Util.getFileFromWeb("http://mat.hachisoftware.com/engine/Gui.jar", "libs");`
`Util.getFileFromWeb("http://mat.hachisoftware.com/engine/IntelliMod.jar", "libs");`

Comment: but not
`Util.getFileFromWeb("http://mat.hachisoftware.com/engine/Gui.jar", "");`
`Util.getFileFromWeb("http://mat.hachisoftware.com/engine/IntelliMod.jar", "");`

Comment: I have change my code and is now working, I was downloading the files to the same folder a the launcher, I have changed it to download to a sub folder

Comment: It because when you don't provide any arguments, I tries to create file at \Gui.jar location which is root location. So, probably You might not have rights to access it.